# Mass Effect 3 Thane is gone

Tags: mass-effect-3

When Thane got stabbed my map showed that he is in the hospital.When I arrived on the Citadel he was still in the hospital.But when I entered the hospital he was gone.Was I too late?Or is this a glitch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am presuming your question is in regards to events that happen after the attack on the citadel and that Thane was stabbed in the chest saving the Salarian councillor.

If you take too long to visit him, he'll die and you'll miss some dialogue.

You can check to see if Thane is considered deceased by the game by checking your memorial wall in the Normandy.

[image: Sniff, bye Thane!]

Comment: Godamn Thane...couldn't wait for me to even say goodbye!He was my fav.